# Add my UserControl to DevExpress ASPxGridView column header

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an ASPxGridView on my page which has a few columns of data.  Basically what I want to do is to add a tooltip (which I have as a user control) to each of the column headers.  I don't think that it is possible to do this in the markup as I don't want to loose any of the functionality already in the grid headers (e.g. filter, etc) so what I need to do is loop through the header cells somehow to add the control in dynamically.

I have tried using the `OnHtmlRowPrepared` event but this does not fire for headers!

I want to achieve something like the following so the tooltip will show on hover (the tooltip is already implemented).

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [GridViewColumn.HeaderCaptionTemplate](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewColumn_HeaderCaptionTemplatetopic) property to implement this.

Here are two samples on using this property:

1. [Using header caption template in aspx](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1320.aspx)
2. [Using header caption template in code behind](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1181.aspx)

Comment: Added the follwing and it worked a treat...                   <HeaderCaption>
                    <div>
                        <dxe:ASPxLabel runat="server" ID="HeaderLabel" Text="<%# Container.Column.Caption %>" />
                        <ucm:Tooltip runat="server" ID="HeaderTooltip" TitleText="<%# Container.Column.Caption %>" ContentText="<%# GetDescription(Container.Column.Name) %>" />
                    </div>
                </HeaderCaption>